# jQuery animate color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, animation

I'm trying to animate a link color change from the current color to an other color.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.article-preview h1 a').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color: #ffffff
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

For some reason it's not working. I'm using the [jQuery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to wrap the hex triplet in a string, change this:

```
color: #ffffff
```

to this:

```
color: "#ffffff"
```

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid like that. Damn the hot weather. Thanks! BTW, do color names have to be wrapped in quotes?

Comment: @wowpatrick, if you don't wrap color names in quotes, the interpreter will think they're variable names. It's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: np. Yes you also have to wrap color names.

Comment: Remember that you have to import `jQuery color` in order for it to work. add this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>`

Comment: Baversjo, you should consider adding @Ramtin's comment to the actual answer. I can confirm that this only works if the jquery.color plugin is added. Otherwise a great answer.

Answer (score 7):

The basic problem is probably that you don't know jQuery's / JavaScript's notations,

writing `#ffffff` would get you *SyntaxError*, because *SharpSign+Letters* doesn't mean anything in JS. 

**Quick Solution:** You have to pass hexa-colors as strings: **`color: "#ffffff"`**

**jQuery supports a few different notations of passed-object for `.css()` & `.animate()` methods,

let me guid you through them.**

## Property names / Keys

*(border, width,...) can be written in 3 ways:*

```
backgroundColor    //DOM formatting
'backgroundColor'  //DOM formatting BUT - passed as a STRING
'background-color' //CSS formatting - passed as a STRING
```

## Property values / Values

*(#ffffff, 0px, none, ... ) can be written in 3 ways*

```
0         // 'pure' number - Integer (useful when pre-calculating pixels)
20.5      //               - Float
'0'       //  number BUT passed as STRING - Integer
'20.5'    //                              - Float
'0px'     //  string
'#ffffff' //  - || -
'auto'    //  - || -
```

You could **rougly** say that everything except pixels is always passed as **string** 

 => that means in quotes (single `'` or double `"` ) or you could of course pass a string variable

So the safest way for beginers would probably be to always use quote notations for both - keys && values.

## ...

## Overall

All this is actually using part of [JSON - JavaScript Object Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

All of this is described in the [jQuery's `.css()` method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

## Beware of

Some bugs in (older) Internet Explorers (see documentation of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) methods)

I did not show example of all string-passed possibilities, for example:

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's
>   padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in
>   a total padding-left of 25px.

JSON object has more valid values than numbers and strings - boolean, array, object, null...