# jquery- Cant animate change in color/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have been following this question [jQuery animate color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967188/jquery-animate-color-change) and have copied their syntax exactly. I'm trying to animate a change in a few css properties on hover, starting with border-color.

Originally I had `$(".panel-default", this).css("border-color", "#ddd");` within my function but that was instant. Now I have:

```
$(".lab1, .lab2, .lab3").hover(function(){

    $(".panel-default", this).animate({"border-color":"green"}, 200);

}, function() {

//    $(".panel-default", this).css("border-color", "#ddd");
//    $(".panel-default > .panel-heading", this).css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
//    $(".panel-default > .panel-heading", this).css("border-color", "#ddd");
//    $(".panel-default > .panel-heading", this).css("color", "#565656");
    $(".panel-default", this).animate({"border-color":"black"}, 200);

});
```

But nothing is happening. How can I animate change in css on hover?

Comment: Is jQuery color plugin defined?

Comment: The plugin referenced at linked Question

Comment: I have and referenced <script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script> but not working

Comment: Is jquery loaded and defined in `window` before `jquery.color.min.js`? Note, `javascript` is not necessary to achieve expected result. `css` `:hover`, `transition`  can be used to animate element `border-color`.

Comment: Could you provide an example with css transitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `css` `:hover`

```css
[class*=lab-] .panel-default {
  display:block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-color: black;
  transition: border-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}
[class*=lab]:hover .panel-default {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="lab-1">
  <div class="panel-default">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lab-2">
  <div class="panel-default">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lab-3">
  <div class="panel-default">
  </div>
</div>
```